# The "disjunction" of two theories

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I have three first-order theories $A,B,C$ at hand such that

> every model of $A$ either satisfies $B$ or satisfies $C$ (or both).

Presumably, none of these theories is finitely axiomatizable.  I am a little uncomfortable with this because I don't know how to write the displayed implication entirely syntactically (which in particular means models are not mentioned).

> Can one rewrite the displayed statement above in terms of first-order *syntactical* notions only?

If not, are there simple (well-known) examples of such $A,B$ and $C$ that can help comfort my mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let theory $B$ have axioms (or theorems) $\theta_i$, and let $C$ have axioms $\varphi_j$, where $i$ and $j$ range over suitable index sets.

Form all possible sentences of the shape $\beta \lor \gamma$, where $\beta$ ranges over all finite conjunctions of the $\theta_i$, and $\gamma$ ranges over all finite conjunctions of the $\varphi_i$.

Comment: But if we admit theories that are **not** *finitely axiomatizable*, to "form all possible sentence of the shape ..." will not be finite, so they will not expressed in "terms of first-order syntactical notions only" .. or I'm wrong ?

Comment: Certainly we admit theories that are not finitely axiomatizable. They include some of the most important (first-order Peano arithmetic, ZF, theory of algebraically closed fields of characteristic $0$, many others). The set of sentences I described in the answer is in general infinite, though each sentence in the set is an ordinary sentence.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Oh, I see.  Thank you very much for the answer.  But why do we need "finite conjunctions"?

Comment: I think the compactness argument does not necessarily work with just plain disjunctions.

Answer (score 0):

I see one problem here. I guess the op means A => B v C, at least if I take verbatim what he writes, and
not A <=> B v C.

[Begin short excurse in infinitary logics.
The following inference rule works fine:

```
  a1  a2  ...         ai in A
  -----------
       A
```

End short excurse infinitary logics.]

So I guess the side condition:

```
  A |- B v C.
```

Means to try to simutaneously proof:

```
  A |- bi v cj     bi in B, cj in C
```

Bye

See also:
SEP on Finite-Quantifier Languages
http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-infinitary/#2